# How to find element from dropdown TextBox in appium android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, appium

I want to select element from drop down in Android Appium
Please let me know what is the way to do it?

Please check the screenshot.[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK2xb.png)

Answer (score 0):

First click on the "Purpose" field, after that the elements will become visible and you will be able to click on dropdown particilar elements. What is the difficulty?

Comment: dropdown elements doesn't have locators to find and click them

Comment: Please check screenshot

Comment: they definitely do have. Cut the elements tree below and find particular locator for the element.

Comment: I am using this method

Comment: Select dropdown = new Select(ep.Purpose);
 
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Meeting");

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "null"

Comment: so inspect that element using uiautomatorviewer or appium desktop, or place breakpoint and find correct locator of that element. You dont need to initialize Select class and then perform some action, you can simply find that WebElement using some common appium methods, such as driver.findElementById or findElementByXpath etc. Probably this element doesnt have text attribute and just ID or accessabilityId or smth else.

Comment: Break Points means . are talking about parent child hierarchy.

Comment: And i am using uiautomatorviewer only to find the elements.

Comment: Firstly, I don't clearly understand you. Secondly, all your issue is about to find locator of an element which is very basic functionality and you better read some manuals about that for example: [that](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/)

Comment: Issue is very clear that i just want to click on any option from dropdown. TextBox which has drop that i have already found. Uiautomator is not at all pointing to any drop down option,, this is my only problem. And this issue is with many people. Check the link below.People are already talking about it. and you are just saying find it, find it .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758547/how-do-i-select-value-from-dropdown-of-a-hybrid-app-using-appium

Comment: Fine, Open appium desktop, expand your dropDown menu, then click on "meeting" element and paste here xpath (or maybe another attribute of that locator such as text, id, description) of that element. It will be better if you paste here a screenshot of that element in DOM

Comment: How to download and use appium desktop for finding element , because i have used only Ui automator till now.

Comment: Why are you asking such question here? try to google it, that question is a very beginning for appium usage

Answer (score 0):

DropDown element doesn't have locators to find it out.
Please check screen shot[DropDown Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMpYE.png)

Answer (score 0):

First click on the "Purpose of vist" text box. Then later try to find the dropdown element locators. if not use the below **xpath** to tap the element.

//*[@text = 'Meeting']

It will help you to tap the elements